# why my code doesn't change the head value in c# or i have to use somethings like pointers?

Tags: c#, pointers, trie

ok, guys, so I was doing the ReplaceWord problems from leetcode in c# ! and I had to initialize a prefix tree. the reason why I use c# that because it has split method which c++ doesn't have.the problem happened when I'm done inserting a word into the trie. usually, when I use c++ and manage the pointer, the tmp will change the last Node.end from false to true. But in c# , the Node of tmp is different from the head, so when I try to change the value of the tmp , the head doesn't affect!. is there any way for me to implement a trie ? without using pointers in c#?
notes: sorry for my bad English, this is the first time I post sth on stack <3

```
public struct Node
    {
        public char val;
        public bool end;
        public Dictionary<char, Node> children;
        public Node(char val)
        {
            this.val = val;
            end = false;
            children = new Dictionary<char, Node>();
        }
    }



public class Solution
    {

        public string ReplaceWords(IList<string> dictionary, string sentence)
        {
           //implement trie 
            Node head = new Node('a');
            foreach (var word in dictionary)
            {
                Node tmp = head;
                for (int i=0;i<word.Length;i++)
                {
                    char charact = word[i];
                    if (!tmp.children.ContainsKey(charact))
                    {
                        Node NEW = new Node(charact);
                        // if(i==word.Length-1)
                        // {
                        //     NEW.end = true;
                        // }


                        tmp.children.Add(charact, NEW);
                    }
                    tmp = tmp.children[charact];
                }
                tmp.end=true;
                // why does this not effect the head end value ? 
            }
            string res = "";
            string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
            for (int i=0;i<words.Length;i++)
            {
                string word=words[i];
                Node travel = head;
                string tmp = "";
                foreach (var charact in word)
                {
                    if (travel.children.ContainsKey(charact))
                    {
                        tmp += charact;
                        travel = travel.children[charact];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tmp = word;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (travel.end == true) break;
                }

                res += tmp;
                if(i!=words.Length-1)
                res += " ";
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you should read https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html - you need to understand the difference between value types and reference types. `Node` is a value type - a struct.

Comment: thank you Jon Skeet for giving the solution, I just can simply change the word struct into class, and then boom, the problem has been solved. no need to change to c++ or use  pointer

Comment: More important than solving this specific problem is understanding the difference for the future. The difference between value types and reference types is *absolutely fundamental* to working effectively in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        public string ReplaceWords(IList<string> dictionary, string sentence)
        { 
            Node head = null;
            Node tmp = null;

            foreach (var word in dictionary)
            {
                for (int i=0;i<word.Length;i++)
                {
                    char charact = word[i];
                    if (!tmp.children.ContainsKey(charact))
                    {
                        Node NEW = new Node(charact);
                        if(head == null)
                        { 
                           head = NEW;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           tmp.next = NEW;
                        }
                        tmp = NEW;
                    }
                    tmp = tmp.children[charact];
                }
            }
            tmp.end = true;
          }
```